# How can I model a hierarchyid type column in EF code-first?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, hierarchy

I'm busy with a strictly academic exercise of deriving a code-based data model for the AdventureWorks2012 sample database. My first issue is with three table columns of type `hieracrhyid`. The EDM wizard in VS2013 Update 4 'kindly' just ignores these columns in the POCOs it generates, and I am quite happy to directly map these columns to `string` properties, but I would like to have a type avialable that actually gives me `hieracrhyid` capabilities, downstream of the actual modle to table mapping.

In the past I have quite successfully used [zgabi's contribution](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/415185), i.e. a fork of the EF code that includes a `HierarchyId` CLR type, but I am actually trying to find a way to achieve this without modifying EF code or using the fork. This in the hope of ultimately finding a generic way to handle any column type not directly supported by EF. Here I would prefer finding, or eventually building, a mechanism for hooking into EF where I can dynamically apply conversion functions between CLR types that EF does support and column types it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not available, but if you are brave you can use the implementation in this community contribution: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/415185

Comment: Sorry @ErikEJ, I really should have added more detail the first time around. I have done that now, so please consider my edit.